# Is there an R function for extract value for Summary(pca,Loading=T) only on loadings Comp.1

Tags: r

How can I extract value from Comp.1 variable after performing Principal Component Analysis?

```
from library(boot)

pca<-princomp(covmat=c)
summary(pca,loading=TRUE)
Importance of components:
                          Comp.1    Comp.2     Comp.3     Comp.4
Standard deviation     1.7877659 0.6147770 0.51612967 0.39944022
Proportion of Variance 0.7990267 0.0944877 0.06659746 0.03988812
Cumulative Proportion  0.7990267 0.8935144 0.96011188 1.00000000

Loadings:
   Comp.1 Comp.2 Comp.3 Comp.4
l1  0.492  0.479  0.724       
b1  0.489  0.538 -0.681       
l2  0.509 -0.502        -0.698
b2  0.510 -0.479         0.709
```

Answer (score 0):

With putting an `$` sign after your `dataframe` of the PCA you can get different options for extracting the values of the PCA you did prior, like `pca$sdev[1]` 
which gives you the sd values for the PC1.